# Streaming, in-place binary patching

Tags: compression, diff

I have series of large binary files, each of which is produced by modifying the previous one. They are stored on a server (the server is just a dumb file store, we can't run programs on it).

To save space I want to store them as diffs. The problem comes when we download the files: they are so large that there is not enough disk space on the client to store both the original file and a diff.

Is there a diff algorithm which will allow us to download the original file to disk, and then apply a patch as it is streamed from the server, in place? AIUI, both xdelta and rdiff can't modify the original file, only create a new copy (which will take too much disk space).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is sadly *no*. Though...

The problem with in place patching is the **mix of insertion and reference to old data**. Insertions need **existing data to be moved** around to let enough place to insert, that is copying backward the end of file (and in the general case it will be pretty slow, and take the **size of the file itself in worst case**). The reference to old data would need to be extremely cautious to reduce the worst case...

With all the constraints to make this possible on client with a real advantage in term of occupied space during patching, the patch would be probably far bigger than what xdelta or rdiff would do. The patching process would be far slower as well.

One possibility with an intelligent server would be to:

- compose all the patches into one meta-patch
- stream the original file patched on the fly (thus making the recomposition on the wire)

Answer (score 0):

The realization idea of ​​sync diff:

1. Clip the data into many blocks with a fixed size;
2. Calculate the blocks that need to be retained in the old data;(can use sync algorithm)
3. Sort retained blocks to a new location by it's in new data order;
4. Download the missing blocks to fill;

Among them, the most difficult is optimize the speed of sort  blocks, Need to make full use of memory or remaining disk space in order to minimize disk I/O；